# How to change hint to label in EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, material-design

I want to get something like this:

[image]

At the beginning I want to display a `hint` in my `EditText` and then when the user clicks on it I want that `hint` to become a label. How I can reach that?

Answer (score 2):

To Your `build.gradle (Module: app)` add this to `dependencies`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
```

In Your layout Add this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/filledTextField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Your email">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

*More information [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields#filled-text-field)*